# My accordian slider stacks images in Firefox but works fine in Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery

This is my site: http://www.blueridgelibertyproject.com/

The slider works fine in Chrome and IE but the images stack without text after refreshing in Firefox and possibly Safari.

Help me please. It's been stumping me a couple of days now and I would love to get it fixed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just checked it in FF14 and Safari 6.0 and did not see any problems.

Comment: could you post some code examples you tried?

Comment: just try to change slideClass: "slider" to slideClass: "#slider"..see if that does the trick...

Comment: just tried that and still the same (#slider) loads fine first time, the when you refresh it stacks.  Again only in firefox.  Both chrome and ie it works fine

Comment: I am lost...did you make any changes because suddenly its working fine for me in firefox even after multiple refresh & I didn't do anything I was just trying to debug it in firebug...which version are you using?

Comment: 16.0.1  and it's still doing it for me

Comment: is it possible to create a fiddel for just the accordion ?

Comment: I'm new to this what's a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ past your code in the respective boxes and add the queries on the left side..to the project then run it and paste the link here for us to see..

Comment: https:// add this to your JQuery Google api...Its not exactly related but some other reload issues are resolved by this trick...It wont harm to give it a try..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jstoking/QTc87/

Answer (score 2):

You have a JavaScript error in Firefox:

From the Error Console:

Timestamp: 12/10/2012 14:29:42
Error: TypeError: jQuery(".sf-menu").mobileMenu is not a function
Source File: http://www.blueridgelibertyproject.com/
Line: 342

Comment: Thank you.  I deleted that to see if it made a difference with the problem I'm experiencing and it was exactly the same.  Loads fine on initial load and then stacks pictures on refresh

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using firebug, or google developer tools.  These are the html errors that your site generates:

```
carouFredSel: No element found for "#portfolio-scroll".
carouFredSel: No element found for "ul.widget-carousel".
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://www.blueridgelibertyproject.com/img/arrows-ffffff.png
carouFredSel: No element found for "#images".
carouFredSel: No element found for "#thumbs".
carouFredSel: No element found for "ul.blog-gallery".
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your code initialization below the div:

example:

```
<!-- first the images for the slider -->
<div id="slide">
<img src="/headslide2.jpg" alt="headslide2" />
<img src="/headslide.jpg" alt="headslide" />
</div>
<!-- next the slide init -->
<script>
jQuery('#slide').carouFredSel({});
</script>
```